# Cannot Arrange Dockpanel children in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, dockpanel

I hosted a wpf control in win form using element host,
and want to arrange children elements in wpf and set their docs to fill the form correctly,
I tried to use DockPanel.SetDock but set not isn't in dockpanel class,
Of course I tried to add system.windows.controls.dockpanel namespace but the only item  in list is "primitives" ,
the PresentationFramework.dll and PresentationCore.dll already were added to references .
what should I do for solving this problem ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my experience DockPanel is always a problem.
Place your custom control inside a Grid without vertical and horizontal alignment.